# We can show bijection between [a,b] and [c,d] in $\mathbb(R)$. But how can one establish an bijection between $[a,b] and (c,d)$.

Tags: analysis, real-numbers, cardinals, interval-arithmetic

We can show bijection between [a,b] and [c,d] in $\mathbb(R)$ by send $x \in [a,b]$ to $(d-b)/(c-a)x + bc-da$.  But how can one establish an bijection between $[a,b]$ and $(c,d)$ can we explicitly define a function?

Comment: Not a continuous one, in either direction. You can use the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan you can find very explicit bijections without resorting to Schroder-Bernstein.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explicit bijection from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$. I leave the details for translating this to $[a,b]$ as an exercise.

Define $f\colon[0,1]\to (0,1)$ as follows.
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/2  &\text{if } x=0\\
1/2^{n+1} &\text{if } x=1/2^n \text{ for } n>0\\
1/3 &\text{if } x=1\\
1/3^{n+1} &\text{if } x=1/3^n \text{ for } n>0\\
x &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Intuitively, you are finding two infinite sequences in your set and using them to make room for the two extra points. You could also just use one infinite sequence and make room by advancing each element by two rather than just one.

Answer (score 1):

By what you said, it is sufficient to define a bijection $f:[c,d]\to(c,d)$.

Let $x_0=c$, and for $n\in\mathbb N^*$, $x_n=c+\frac{d-c}n$.

Put $f(x_n)=x_{n+2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and $f(x)=x$ for any other $x\in[c,d]$.